# get a specified parameter in a route?

Tags: laravel, routes, slug

I have a route with multi parameters. How could I get `slug` in below route?

```
Route::apiResource('/tournaments/{tournament}/structures/{slug}', '\SingleController');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it directly, [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters) for your reference:

```
public function index($tournament, $slug) {}

public function show($tournament, $slug, $id) {}

public function store($tournament, $slug) {}
```